# MCU - Generally speaking, How to read data from a TX pin?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, gpio

I have a SAML21J18A Board (from Atmel, with an AVR processor), plus a SIM908 development board. So, this is the technical specs, but I would like to have the answer to a very general question:

When you wire one of your MCU's GPIO pins to a "TX" pin on another peripheral, what is the common way to read the data from this TX pin ? Do I have to use the I2C protocol ? Do I have to read like over the time the status of the GPIO ? Is it even possible to read complex data with the GPIO, not only true or false states ?

Thanks for you answer in advance, I am kinda lost on this subject.

Comment: What is a "tx pin"? It entirely depends on what that pin does of course. Is it a GPIO pin? I2C? Something else?

Comment: That's the thing, on the SIM908, it is written everywhere "GSM_TX", but it doesn't give any information about how this pin communicates.

Comment: The manual says: "For GPS NMEA information output, debugging and upgrading firmware". Sounds like something used by the manufacturer? In which case they probably won't tell you what communication interface there is. "If these pins are unused, keep open".

Comment: Anyway this question is off-topic for SO, you should post similar questions at http://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but hardware.

Comment: I see this as an so question not an electronics question.  a programming question on how to use the part programmatically not electrically.

Comment: The question is even more confusing because you simply don't read data from a TX (Transmit) pin. You read from RX and write to TX. However, in this case the actual question appears to be "how to read data from a GPIO pin"? Which obviously includes first configuring it for RX.

Comment: @Lundin NMEA is typically UART-type serial data, in plain human readable text, at a "usual suspects" baud rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pin is labeled as "TX", and especially if there is a corresponding "RX" pin, then it's likely a UART.  I2C pins are typically labelled DAta and CLock.  SPI pins are typically labelled MOSI/SIMO/SCLK or DI/DO/CLK.

It's possible to hook any of these signals to a GPIO pin and write a software driver to "[bit-bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_banging)" the interface to implement the protocol.  But you'd be *much* better off connecting the pin to the appropriate serial port pin on your microcontroller and let the microcontroller's hardware peripheral do the detailed work.

If this TX pin is truly a UART then you should connect it to the RX pin on your microcontroller's UART.

Answer (score 1):

The SIM908 uses the UART protocol to communicate with a host. AT commands are the language the module understands. The GSM_TX pin is used by the modem to send responses to the host whereas the GSM_RX pin is used to receive commands from the host, which is your SAM board in this case. You may also notice GPS_TX and GPS_RX pins on the board.

A digital GPIO pin sends/receives data in terms of logic levels, HIGH or LOW. Since a standard UART transmission consists of a start bit, 8-bit data and a stop bit (all of which can be expressed as a series of HIGHs and LOWs sent at a specific constant frequency), a digital GPIO pin can be used, with the right timing, to receive and transmit data between the module and the host; this is called bit-banging.

It is however more convenient and reliable to use the built-in UART hardware wired to specific pins on your board. Perform the proper initialization for the UART peripheral, making sure to select the right baud, and begin by issuing "AT" to the module; you should receive "OK" if all goes well. If you receive gibberish, it means the module isnt set to auto-baud and you are using the wrong baud, which means you have to try all the standard baud values from 4800 upwards. If you show your code, you could get better help.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a uart pin as already answered.  What can you do with a gpio pin, you can do most if not all of the serial protocols (with a few pins), uart, spi, i2c, mdio, etc.  Using what is called bit banging.  for output pins you generally have to use an internal timer of some sort to time the duration between state changes so that outside the part the transitions are timed correctly to meet whatever timing spec is required for that protocol.  It creates an appreciation for what the hardware does for you, and is something that is trivial to implement in hardware (esp when you want several different ones going on at the same time) but harder in software as it can burn a lot of cpu cycles, and not always be accurately timed.   Receiving bit banged stuff can be harder if you cant sample and process the state changes fast enough, receiving a uart signal for example, a spi slave, etc.  digital logic is only zero and one states (And x and y and z in simulation, and z in real life) complex protocols are nothing but zero and one states in series or parallel or both.

Technically it is possible to do all of these and more complex serial protocols with gpio if you have the sampling rate and processing power.